# How do I remove a specific row in ggplot in r when working with y element of ggplot()? (Explanation better below)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Currently graphing the below scatterplot and I have a "null" category on the x-axis. I have used which for NumofBed to remove the rows with "null" in them, but how do I remove this category from the sales_price y? (I'm getting the error that my x and y numbers don't match up because sales_price is including the rows where NumofBed is null).

```
scatterBedValue <- ggplot(housedata, aes(x=which(NumofBed != "null"), y=sales_price))
```

Graph below is using scatterBedValue <- ggplot(housedata, aes(x=NumofBed, y=sales_price)) 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's cleaner to do data-side filtering first, and then plot.

```
library(tidyverse);
housedata %>%
    filter(NumofBed != "NULL") %>%
    ggplot(aes(NumofBed, sales_price)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: What if I don't want to completely eliminate these data points from my data set because they have other valuable info? Or I guess I could just do this for the graphs where I need them eliminated? Is there a way to save this new data frame under another name like "housedataBedClean"

Comment: No problem @namore; by the way, in my example I'm not eliminating any data from `housedata`; you can confirm this by inspecting `housedata` after the plot.

Comment: So how long does this filter last? A certain number of commands? Because I just ran into the issue of trying to do calculations on these vectors and there were still "null" strings in them.

Comment: Additionally, why doesn't the following code work to find the average value added per bed? `housedata %>% filter(NumofBed != "null") %>% avgBedValueAdd = mean( housedata$sales_price / as.numeric(housedata$NumofBed)) print(avgBedValueAdd) print(housedata$NumofBed)`

Comment: @namore With `magrittr`'s `%>%` you just chain commands; the last command terminates the chain. You can store the chain in a new object, to save all changes/manipulations/transformations. Have a look at a `tidyverse`/`dplyr` tutorial if you want to know more. This would go way beyond this question. It's a very neat (tidy) way of working with data.